# JDT eclipse Using deployable plugins and fragments

Tags: jar, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-jdt

I have a working JDT plugin, that takes runtime arguments(till now i have been passing through eclipse Runtime Arguments)

Now, I need to export it as a jar,so that other people can also use it.

I exported it using Export->Deployable Plugins and Fragments to  particular directory.

When I try to execute this jar file from my cmd it gives the error:

no main manifest attribute, in testPlugin_1.0.0.jar

Can anyone help me run this jar from command line?
PS: the Plugin project does have a manifest.xml as foloows:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: TestPlugin Plug-in
Bundle-SymbolicName: testPlugin; singleton:=true
Bundle-Version: 1.0.0
Bundle-Activator: com.codechanger.ResourceCloseActivator
Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.ui,
 org.eclipse.core.runtime,
 org.eclipse.core.databinding,
 org.eclipse.ant.core,
 org.eclipse.jdt,
 org.eclipse.jdt.core,
 org.eclipse.core.resources,
 org.eclipse.jface.text,
 org.eclipse.jface.databinding

Eclipse-LazyStart: true
```

Google says jar should have a Manifest.xml with a Main class but my JDT plugin is triggered by start method when i run using osgi framework, not main class.

Comment: ok,thanks.. can you giude me as to how I should go about it? I have an activator that parses all files in the project and makes the required changes and saves them.Also what about the runtime arguments that I need to pass? Where shall I be passing them..

Answer (score 0):

You can't run a plugin directly from the command line, you will have to install it into Eclipse and run Eclipse, or write a Rich Client Program (RCP) that has a GUI just to run your code.

You can pass arguments for the program by specifying them on the command line you use to start Eclipse.